# iOS upload to Amazon S3 bucket with my bucket namespace

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am using Amazon iOS Sdk for uploading images in S3 bucket and the link generated after upload is "**https ://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKET/MYIMAGE.PNG**" but I want it to be like "**https:/MYBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/MYIMAGE.PNG**" . How to achieve this?

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"MYIMAGE.PNG"
                                                          inBucket:@"MYBUCKET"] autorelease];
por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
por.data = imageData;
por.delegate = self;

[self.s3 putObject:por];
```